# Error in generating pdf from .tex file

Tags: pdftex, errors

I am first time user of Latex. I have some .tex files which I need to read in pdf version. They have equations and figures attached in them. I was readin the first document of "about" but it did not open. I used `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 01-about.tex` command for generating pdf.
I have attached the .tex code and the .log generated.

.tex file:

```
\section{About {\psiboil}}
\label{sec_about}

{\psiboil} ({\sf P}arallel {\sf SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a
three-dimensional, numerical solver for single- and two-phase flows 
with or without heat transfer. It has the capability to simulate conjugate 
heat transfer problems as well. The discretization of governing equations is
based on the~$2^{nd}$ order accurate Finite Volume~(FV) method,
on staggered orthogonal grids. % REF
%
Two-phase flows are simulated with surface tracking algorithm,
based on conservative Level Set~(LS) approach. % REF
%
Linear solvers are based on the Krylov's sub-space family of algorithms,
which can be accelerated with an algebraic multigrid method. % REF

{\psiboil} is written in {\tt C++} programming language and uses Message
Passing Interface ({\tt MPI}) for parallelization. It compiles on most
Linux-based computers\footnote{\tt www.linux.org}. 
The compilation procedure relies on {\tt autotools},
as well as on the {\tt make} utility. On most computational platforms, 
compilation consists of running {\tt configure}, followed by {\tt make}. 
%
{\psiboil} has been compiled on Linux-based PCs, clusters, as
well as main-frame computers such as Cray-XT3\footnote{Cray is
a registered trademark of Cray Inc.\ ({\tt www.cray.com}).}.
It is also possible to compile it on Windows~XP\footnote{Windows~XP
is a registered trademark of Microsoft Inc.\ ({\tt www.microsoft.com}).}.
Cygwin system\footnote{\tt www.cygwin.com} and without~{\tt MPI}
support.

The development of {\psiboil} has started in the summer of~2006,
at Paul Scherrer Institute~(PSI), as an integral part of the project
on Multi-Scale Modeling Analysis~(MSMA), which focuses on mechanistic
modeling of boiling phenomena at multiple scales. Initially, it is
available only to PSI personnel working on the MSMA project. But, should
it prove useful, it might spread further among the academic
community, presumably under a {\tt GNU} license\footnote{www.gnu.org}.
%
The main purpose of {\psiboil} is not to compete with commercial
Computational Fluid Dynamics~(CFD) packages, but rather to serve
as a tool for academic community.

Since it's aim is not to compete with commercial CFD codes, {\psiboil} 
is not an integral program capable to solve a general fluid
flow problem. Rather, it is a suite of objects an algorithms 
which are used as blocks for building programs for particular flow problems. 
As you will see in this tutorial, for every problem being solved, 
a new program\footnote{A new {\tt main()} function, embodied into a
separate~{\tt main.cpp} file.} is written. These programs are supposed
to be short and highly specialized for a particular task. 

Following this rationale, {\psiboil} does not have any input files. 
It's  main program is re-written for each problem being solved and 
actually serves as an input file itself.
```

The .log file with error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.11.18)  20 NOV 2021 18:28
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**01-about.tex
(./01-about.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \section
            {About {\psiboil}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \section{A
              bout {\psiboil}}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no A in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \section{About {\psiboil
                            }}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--3
[]
 []

! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 {\psiboil
             } ({\sf P}arallel {\sf SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 {\psiboil} (
                {\sf P}arallel {\sf SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 {\psiboil} ({\sf
                     P}arallel {\sf SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no P in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 {\psiboil} ({\sf P}arallel {\sf
                                    SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a


 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9 strings out of 494953
 172 string characters out of 6180976
 47251 words of memory out of 5000000
 3394 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 18i,5n,12p,103b,104s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You need to compile the main file, for example `main.tex`, which includes the call of `01-about.tex`. The main file needs to have a documentclass and an `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

Comment: as a first time user you seem to have found a very old tutorial, `\tt` and `\sf` have not been defined by default in latex for almost 30 years.  `\textsf{P}` and `\texttt{make}` would be the standard latex markup.

Comment: Search about the minimal structure of a "Hello, Word" in LaTeX. Then you will notice that you have only a chunk of code, not a compilable LaTeX document.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is caused by a malformed input file. It needs `\documentclass` and proper `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile by its own, it must be a specific section of a bigger document. However, I fixed your code by supposing that the command `\psiboil` is something like $\psi_boil$ in math mode. Here's the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\psiboil}{$\psi_{boil}$}
\begin{document}

\section{About {\psiboil}}
\label{sec_about}
{\psiboil} ({\sf P}arallel {\sf SI}mulator of {\sf Boil}ing phenomena) is a
three-dimensional, numerical solver for single- and two-phase flows with or without heat transfer. It has the capability to simulate conjugate 
heat transfer problems as well. The discretization of governing equations isbased on the~$2^{nd}$ order accurate Finite Volume~(FV) method,
on staggered orthogonal grids. % REF
Two-phase flows are simulated with surface tracking algorithm,based on conservative Level Set~(LS) approach. % REF
Linear solvers are based on the Krylov's sub-space family of algorithms,
which can be accelerated with an algebraic multigrid method. % REF
{\psiboil} is written in {\tt C++} programming language and uses Message
Passing Interface ({\tt MPI}) for parallelization. It compiles on most
Linux-based computers\footnote{\tt www.linux.org}. 
The compilation procedure relies on {\tt autotools},
as well as on the {\tt make} utility. On most computational platforms, compilation consists of running {\tt configure}, followed by {\tt make}. 
{\psiboil} has been compiled on Linux-based PCs, clusters, as well as main-frame computers such as Cray-XT3\footnote{Cray is a registered trademark of Cray Inc.\ ({\tt www.cray.com}).}.
It is also possible to compile it on Windows~XP\footnote{Windows~XP is a registered trademark of Microsoft Inc.\ ({\tt www.microsoft.com}).}. Cygwin system\footnote{\tt www.cygwin.com} and without~{\tt MPI} support.
The development of {\psiboil} has started in the summer of~2006, at Paul Scherrer Institute~(PSI), as an integral part of the project 
on Multi-Scale Modeling Analysis~(MSMA), which focuses on mechanistic modeling of boiling phenomena at multiple scales. Initially, it is
available only to PSI personnel working on the MSMA project. But, should it prove useful, it might spread further among the academic community, presumably under a {\tt GNU} license\footnote{www.gnu.org}.
The main purpose of {\psiboil} is not to compete with commercial Computational Fluid Dynamics~(CFD) packages, but rather to serve as a tool for academic community. 
Since it's aim is not to compete with commercial CFD codes, {\psiboil}  is not an integral program capable to solve a general fluid flow problem. Rather, it is a suite of objects an algorithms  which are used as blocks for building programs for particular flow problems.  As you will see in this tutorial, for every problem being solved, 
a new program\footnote{A new {\tt main()} function, embodied into a separate~{\tt main.cpp} file.} is written. These programs are supposed to be short and highly specialized for a particular task. 
Following this rationale, {\psiboil} does not have any input files. It's  main program is re-written for each problem being solved and actually serves as an input file itself. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your `\psibol` command is not well defined.  It seems to me that you were trying to use the world `PSIBOIL` in sans-serif and that seems to be the problem.

As @L Mascolo pointed out, you just need to create a command that does not contain any errors and does not get in conflict with other stuff you have around.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\psiboil}{\textsf{PSIBOIL}}

\begin{document}
    \section{About {\psiboil}}
    \label{sec_about}

    {\psiboil} (\textsf{P}arallel \textsf{SI}mulator of \textsf{Boil}ing phenomena) is a
three-dimensional, numerical solver for single- and two-phase flows 
with or without heat transfer. It has the capability to simulate conjugate 
heat transfer problems as well. The discretization of governing equations is
based on the~$2^{nd}$ order accurate Finite Volume~(FV) method,
on staggered orthogonal grids. % REF
%
Two-phase flows are simulated with surface tracking algorithm,
based on conservative Level Set~(LS) approach. % REF
%
Linear solvers are based on the Krylov's sub-space family of algorithms,
which can be accelerated with an algebraic multigrid method. % REF

{\psiboil} is written in {\tt C++} programming language and uses Message
Passing Interface ({\tt MPI}) for parallelization. It compiles on most
Linux-based computers\footnote{\tt www.linux.org}. 
The compilation procedure relies on {\tt autotools},
as well as on the {\tt make} utility. On most computational platforms, 
compilation consists of running {\tt configure}, followed by {\tt make}. 
%
{\psiboil} has been compiled on Linux-based PCs, clusters, as
well as main-frame computers such as Cray-XT3\footnote{Cray is
a registered trademark of Cray Inc.\ ({\tt www.cray.com}).}.
It is also possible to compile it on Windows~XP\footnote{Windows~XP
is a registered trademark of Microsoft Inc.\ ({\tt www.microsoft.com}).}.
Cygwin system\footnote{\tt www.cygwin.com} and without~{\tt MPI}
support.

The development of {\psiboil} has started in the summer of~2006,
at Paul Scherrer Institute~(PSI), as an integral part of the project
on Multi-Scale Modeling Analysis~(MSMA), which focuses on mechanistic
modeling of boiling phenomena at multiple scales. Initially, it is
available only to PSI personnel working on the MSMA project. But, should
it prove useful, it might spread further among the academic
community, presumably under a {\tt GNU} license\footnote{www.gnu.org}.
%
The main purpose of {\psiboil} is not to compete with commercial
Computational Fluid Dynamics~(CFD) packages, but rather to serve
as a tool for academic community.

Since it's aim is not to compete with commercial CFD codes, {\psiboil} 
is not an integral program capable to solve a general fluid
flow problem. Rather, it is a suite of objects an algorithms 
which are used as blocks for building programs for particular flow problems. 
As you will see in this tutorial, for every problem being solved, 
a new program\footnote{A new {\tt main()} function, embodied into a
separate~{\tt main.cpp} file.} is written. These programs are supposed
to be short and highly specialized for a particular task. 

Following this rationale, {\psiboil} does not have any input files. 
It's  main program is re-written for each problem being solved and 
actually serves as an input file itself.

 \end{document}
```

The output:

[image]